# Changing the home page is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvcroutehandler

In my project the initial route config was like below

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
  {
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
   routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
 defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Now I changed to

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
  {
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
   routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
 defaults: new { controller = "Pro123", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Then I rebuild the solution and run it again @ local system. Still it is going to Login view of the Home controller. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Is there an `[Authorize]` attribute applied to the controller or globally?

Comment: @haim770 no.there no [Authorize] attribute